# Is it allowed to insert 2 application in 1 diagram (activity and sequence diagram)?

Tags: uml, use-case, sequence-diagram, activity-diagram

So i'm making this application to send a message from my android to another android through the java server on PC.
So i'm confused on how to make this activity because there are like more than 1 user that's involved in this diagram (because it's sending and receiving application) so this is the activity diagram on how the android receive a message from anpther android.

and the sequence is almost the same as the activity. it has 2 users in it. am i right on this activity and sequence diagram ? please tell me what's wrong on that diagram picture

here is the image : https://postimg.cc/nsCcGcph

Answer (score 1):

That's fine this way. The columns down are Partitions classified with the according Actor or Class (rather than just being swim lines). It's just natural that ADs and SDs have things in common. The first is more appropriate for business and the second for technical viewers.

N.B. There's a technical flaw in your 2nd Action: The flow coming from the bottom needs to be merged with the one coming from the left. Use a diamond like the one seen without text inside.

Comment: can you be more spesific please ? like from which user are you talking about?

Comment: Hm. I don't see where your issue is :-/ Am I using the word "user" anywhere?

Comment: no but can you explain like where is columns down or 2nd action. Ok to the point. is my diagram correct or not? and which should i remove the swim line and what should i change to?

Comment: Read my first sentence in the answer. It's not visible if you use just (graphical) swim lines or Partitions. The latter are model elements and can by classified.